# Locating the directory of localhost

Tags: windows, localhost

An useful editor (**[Lugaru's Epsilon Programmer's Editor](https://www.lugaru.com/)**), is running on my localhost at port 8888 (i.e., `localhost:8888`), when I open the offline help through the application.

Below is a screenshot:
[image]

And below is the `netstat` result:

[image]

All I want to know, is just to find, where are the man files are stored in the disk. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Search for Welcome.html

Comment: Welcome.html will contain links to the man files. That way you can find them.

Comment: @Ramhound: No luck there is no such file, in the entire system drive...I already have tried this option before posting this question...

Comment: They are not necessarily stored as separate files. They may well be bundled in a single file or even embedded into the server application itself.

Comment: Your question makes no mention of that fact

Comment: @DanielB: I hope you are right.

Comment: I’m not sure why you think that’s positive...? Or are you perhaps concerned about the editor being a security vulnerability or something?

Comment: It tell you in the address bar. `\\servername:port\sharename\folder\file.ext`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to capture filesystem activity with free sysinternal tool [procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), with a filter that is only showing paths containing ".html".
After configuring procmon start to click a few different pages of the webpage.
You should now see the webserver process accessing those html files with full path to file.

Comment: Nice tool, but it doesn't solve my purpose...:)